# Save zoomed image from camera

Tags: iphone

I am developing a camera application for iphone/ipad. 
We are using an overlay for displaying the camera app on top of the viewfinder.
Currently i am trying to save the zoomed image. We are able to zoom the image on viewfinder. But when we save the image it gets saved in the original size.
To solve this we are scaling the zoomed image using the following code :

```
UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(v.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, zoomvalue,zoomvalue);
[v drawRect:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Using the above code we are able to get the zoomed image.
However, we need to crop the center portion of the scaled image and save the same. We are not getting the same.

Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

if You are using `UIImagePickerController` to capture image and zoom your image there then you can get the edited image by getting `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` from picker `NSDictionary` something like this -

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    img =  [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] retain];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Yes I am using UIImagePickerController only.

Comment: then use "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage" key in info dictionary.. and don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you! Happy SOing..

Comment: @Sheetal if this suggestion address your issue, accept it as answer, upvote it if you think it helps (even tough it is not the answer you are looking for) else just write few lines what is expected and what not .... Asking specific questions and neglecting the response is very very irritating.  +1 for his effort.